# App or service that blocks robocallers

Tags: iphone-app, captcha

I tried RoboKiller but it didn't work and I still received robo calls, 3 on the first day. It blocked 0 robo calls during my 6 days of trial. It is ineffective because it uses white lists and black lists and the robo callers use spoofed fake caller ids. I'm unable to block all 10 million phone numbers in the same area code, and I may want to speak to the real owners of those phone numbers some time in the future. (In fact, I rejected a real caller from my same area code thinking it was a spammer.) I would like an app that is able to block these calls, perhaps by obtaining the real caller id the same way police are able to trace calls. Ideally, I would like a service that presents an audio CAPTCHA. I have that feature on my land VOIP ("Press x to complete your call") and I receive absolutely 0 spam calls.

Comment: This is a feature that would be provided by your service provider; you should contact them to pursue this.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin AT&T does not provide this service. They have an app, but does not work on iPhone 5 or pre-pay service.

Comment: If you live in the US, have you already added your phone to the Do Not Call registry right?

Comment: @MiCl They don't even provide the correct caller ID. Why would they follow the Do Not Call registry? They are criminals, like a mass shooter who doesn't follow gun laws, albeit less blood.